# web form to get data from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I recently came across an article on How to create a web form to get data from Google Sheets. Which worked out perfect for me. But I now am looking for it to search multiple "worksheets" so far this only does a single sheet. Here is the code (edited my spreadsheet id)

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the Sandbox mode
        .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
 
/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  var result = "";
  if(formObject.searchtext){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(formObject.searchtext);
  }
  return result;
}

//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = 'spreadsheet id'; //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRage        = 'Data!A2:G';                                    //** CHANGE !!!
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRage).values;
  var ar = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

Comment: If you have permission to access the other spreadsheet you can always open them with openById() or openByUrl().

Comment: Yes I have permission! where would this go on that code?

Comment: Since you're using the API then just provide a different spreadsheet id.

Comment: I might also consider the use of [textFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: You could also do a lot of what you are attempting by using a web app as sort of an api.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into what you suggested! This is the website I was referring too: https://www.bpwebs.com/create-web-forms-to-get-data-from-google-sheets/    I have it all set up on my website works well but i need to make an additional sheets to have it search as well

Comment: Well then just give it the id of the spreadsheet and you should be good to go.

Comment: each additional worksheet is like this (my spreadsheet id)/edit#gid=49372983. I do not know where to add the new "/edit#gid=49372983"

Comment: oh you talking sheets not spreadsheets so then your  variable `dataRage` should change it's page.

Comment: yes that! i see it, and put my data sheet in. deployed it and nothing. //SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = ''; //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRage        = 'Data!A2:G';   'Data2!A2:G';                                 //** CHANGE !!!
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRage).values;
  var ar = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}

Comment: can this also be done by just searching sequence of numbers and not text. I appreciate your help in all this!